# Textbox's Textchanged event not fire in chrome

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, google-chrome

i am Creating a page that search all client details...
i am also using json for autocomplete textbox with data of datatable...

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#<%=txtSearch.ClientID %>").autocomplete({
        source: function (request, response) {
            $.ajax({
                url: '<%=ResolveUrl("~/Service.asmx/GetCustomers") %>',
                data: "{ 'prefix': '" + request.term + "'}",
                dataType: "json",
                type: "POST",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                success: function (data) {
                    response($.map(data.d, function (item) {
                        return {
                            label: item.split('-')[0],
                            val: item.split('-')[1]
                        }
                    }))
                },
                error: function (response) {
                    alert(response.responseText);
                },
                failure: function (response) {
                    alert(response.responseText);
                }
            });
        },
        select: function (e, i) {
            $("#<%=hfCustomerId.ClientID %>").val(i.item.val);
        },
        minLength: 1
    });

});
```

i want to view data of that selected name on textbox on textchanged  event,
their setup of textbgox looks like..`

```
 <asp:TextBox ID="txtSearch" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True" 
        ontextchanged="txtSearch_TextChanged"></asp:TextBox>
```

That textchenged event trigger properly in mozilla, but not working in chrome,,
can anyone suggests some solution....

Comment: why are you using  AutoPostBack="True" ?

Comment: AutoPostBack="True" is used to fire any server control's event

Comment: remove  AutoPostBack="True" if you dont use then try on chrome.

Comment: if i remove that mozilla doesn't support that textchanged event

Comment: please try i will work.

Comment: why u need ontextchanged server side event if you have autocomplete text??

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest calling server side's textbox onchange event after selecting a value from the autocomplete list as,

```
...
select: function (e, i) {
        $("#<%=hfCustomerId.ClientID %>").val(i.item.val);
        __doPostBack("txtSearch", "TextChanged");
    },
    minLength: 1
});
```

and remove autopostback property of that textbox as we are firing it from client side.

Or you can make an ajax call on select event and populate required data in client side itself.

Answer (score 0):

```
`  $(document).ready(function () {
        var prm = Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance();
        prm.add_initializeRequest(InitializeRequest);
        prm.add_endRequest(EndRequest);           
        InitAutoCompl();
    });

    function InitializeRequest(sender, args) {
    }

    function EndRequest(sender, args) {           
        InitAutoCompl();
    }

    function InitAutoCompl() {
        $("#<%=txtSearch.ClientID %>").autocomplete({
            source: function (request, response) {
                $.ajax({
                    url: ''<%=ResolveUrl("~/Service.asmx/GetCustomers") %>',
                    data: "{ 'prefix': '" + request.term + "'}",
                    dataType: "json",
                    type: "POST",
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    success: function (data) {
                        response($.map(data.d, function (item) {
                            return {
                                label: item.split('@@')[0],
                                val: item.split('@@')[1]
                            }
                        }))
                    },
                    error: function (response) {
                        alert(response.responseText);
                    },
                    failure: function (response) {
                        alert(response.responseText);
                    }
                });
            },

            minLength: 1, change: function (event, ui) { __doPostBack("txtSearch", "TextChanged"); }
        });
    }
```

and remove Autopostback="true" from TextBox
 `